# Pixel USB C Earbuds choppy sound skipping music

Tags: google, huawei, huawei-p20

On a HUAWEI P20 lite (Nova E3)
I have tried the basics in sound and use audio though USB
I was told on Reddit that they would work in the devices sub/

Also, when I try to answer a call, it hangs up.

I have searched but it comes up with completely irrelevant topics.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After everything and reading articles from Google I reached the conclusion that the earbuds are faulty, so I sent them back for claiming refund.